# Starting a simple WebSocket Server with Spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to start a simple websocket server in a spring integration application.

I build my application thanks to the following dependancies :

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-websocket")
    compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-ip")
    compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-websocket")
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind')
    compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-feed")   
}
```

I launch my application thanks to the following Java file :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplication("/integration.xml").run(args);
        System.out.println("Hit Enter to terminate");
        System.in.read();
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

Here is my "integartion.xml" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:feed="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed"
        xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
        xmlns:ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/websocket"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed/spring-integration-feed.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/websocket http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/websocket/spring-integration-websocket.xsd">

    <int-ip:udp-inbound-channel-adapter id="udpReceiver"
        channel="udpOutChannel"
        port="11111"
        receive-buffer-size="500"
        multicast="true"
        multicast-address="225.6.7.8"/>
    <int:object-to-string-transformer input-channel="udpOutChannel" output-channel="stringified"/>
    <bean id="nmeaParser" class="transformers.NMEAParser"/>   
    <int:transformer input-channel="stringified" ref="nmeaParser" output-channel="parsedData"/>   
    <int:channel id="jsondata"/>
    <int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="parsedData" output-channel="jsondata"/>
    <ws:server-container id="server" path="/position"/>        
    <ws:outbound-channel-adapter container="server" channel="jsondata"/>
</beans>
```

As you can see, I create an UDP inbound channel. This channels works like a charm. I am able to see that data are sucessfully passed to my "NMEAParser" bean.

I think that my Websocket server doesn't work because :

*I can't connect to it with wscat*... When I try to do :

```
wscat -c ws://127.0.0.1:8080/position
```

I receive a "CONNECTION REFUSED", the same message I receive when nothing is launched.

*In the Spring log's I can read this* :

```
Starting beans in phase 0    
Adding {object-to-string-transformer} as a subscriber to the 'udpOutChannel' channel    
Channel 'application:8080.udpOutChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).   
started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0    
Adding {transformer} as a subscriber to the 'stringified' channel    
Channel 'application:8080.stringified' has 1 subscriber(s).    
started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1    
Adding {object-to-json-transformer} as a subscriber to the 'parsedData' channel    
Channel 'application:8080.parsedData' has 1 subscriber(s).    
started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2    
Adding {websocket:outbound-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the 'jsondata' channel    
Channel 'application:8080.jsondata' has 1 subscriber(s).    
started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3    
Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel    
Channel 'application:8080.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).    
started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger    
Starting beans in phase 1073741823    
started udpReceiver    
Started Application in 0.792 seconds (JVM running for 1.121)
```

We can see here that all my beans are launched, except the bean "server" which is my server container. There is no trace of this bean in this log message.

To write my application I read carrefully [this sampe](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/applications/stomp-chat/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/samples/chat/stomp/server/stomp-server.xml) and [this doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/web-sockets.html).

**What am I doing wrong, or what I forgot ?**

Comment: How are you deploying your app? Which [websocket runtime](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server) are you using?

Comment: Interesting question. Actually I didn't choose any websocket runtime. I updated my question with my Main.java...

Comment: In the sample, there is this line : @ImportResource(<path to integration.xml>. Does this line allow Spring integration to instanciate a websocket runtime ?

Comment: Good - it's a Spring Boot app so you'll get a runtime. It will run on port 8080 by default, not 80. Try `wscat -c ws://127.0.0.1:8080/position`.

Comment: Oups, sorry, my question was not uptodate... So I updated it. Actually I try on port 8080, and I've got the connection refused.

Comment: Is it normal that we don't see anything about the websocket server bean in the logs ? All other beans are present.

Comment: The server is not a `Lifecycle` bean so you won't see a `started` for it. I suggest you turn on debug logging for all of `org.springframework`. If you can't figure it out from the logs post it somewhere like pastebin (probably too big for here).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103517/discussion-between-abarral-and-gary-russell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the chat after our lengthy comment back and forth, you need `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket` in your dependencies, this will bring in `spring-boot-starter-web` and `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat` transitively, giving you a websocket runtime.